# decorator to change view function logic if user is anonymous

Tags: python, flask

I currently have a view that returns different responses depending on if the user is anonymous or not, atm I'm using:

```
@app.route("/anonymous")
def anonymous_page():
    if current_user.is_anonymous:
        return render_template("anonymous_page.html")
    return render_template("user_page.html")
```

I want to make a decorator, let's call it `@show_only_to_anonymous`, that can be used on a normal view function with a single return statement, that will do something like this:

```
@app.route("/anonymous")
@show_only_to_anonymous
# if the user is anonymous, return the decorated function's view,
# elif the user is NOT anonymous, return "user_page.html"
def anonymous_page():
        return render_template("anonymous_page.html")
```

I know there is a `login_required` decorator, I went to take a look at the source code [here](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/flask_login/utils.html#login_required), and it uses `LocalProxy` for `current_user` under the hood, tried to replicate that and failed,

I guess my understanding of the flask framework is lacking as I am kinda new to it, anyone has an idea?

edit:
I managed to get it working by looking at the source code of flask-login, the file is: `flask_login/utils.py`, I used the same `flask` and `werkzeug.local` functions and other objects and created a new file in my project which I named `custom_decorators.py` and imported as a module in my `routes.py` file, these are the contents of `custom_decorators.py`:

```
from functools import wraps
from werkzeug.local import LocalProxy
from flask import _request_ctx_stack, has_request_context, current_app

current_user = LocalProxy(lambda: _get_user())

def _get_user():
    if has_request_context() and not hasattr(_request_ctx_stack.top, 'user'):
        current_app.login_manager._load_user()

    return getattr(_request_ctx_stack.top, 'user', None)

def show_only_to_anonymous(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
        if not current_user.is_anonymous:
            return current_app.view_functions['show_to_known_users'](*args, **kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_view
```

now in my `routes.py` I can do this:

```
# this page can only be seen by anonymous users
@app.route("/anonymous")
@show_only_to_anonymous
def anonymous_page():
    return render_template("anonymous_page.html")

# this will be called if a logged in user goes to mywebsite.com/anonymous:
@app.route("/show_to_known_users")
def show_to_known_users():
    return redirect(url_for("user_page.html", code=301))
```

this solution feels a bit 'hacky', is there a better way?

Comment: Hi Jean, could you add more details about your code? like the flask entrypoint and show_only_to_anonymous decorators. Thx

Comment: edited the post :) lemme know if there's anything else u need to know, basically I am want to have view functions run differently for anonymous users, but I want to add that functionality in a decorator rather than add if statements in each view function